# Jenkins Pipeline get variable from git commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a question about a Jenkins pipeline. I would like to have a variable that gets data from the git commit.

For example, if the git commit says "Version 1.0.0" then the variable in the Jenkins file should be "1.0.0". If the commit are 2.0.0 then the variable should be 2.0.0

I've already seen that with the option `changelog` in Jenkins you can get data from the Git Commit, unfortunately I don't know how to put this data into a variable ?

Can anyone help me ?

I have already seen and tried the following

```
pipeline {
    when {
        changelog '1.0.0.0'
    }
    environment {
        nicevariable = " here should be the gitcommit see changelog"
    }



    agent none
    stages {
        stage("first") {
            sh "echo ${nicevariable}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define environment variable [dynamically](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables-dynamically), e.g.:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        GIT_MESSAGE = """${sh(
            script: 'git log --no-walk --format=format:%s ${GIT_COMMIT}', 
            returnStdout: true
            )}"""
    }
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Message: --${GIT_MESSAGE}--"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the problem if I make an echo GIT_MESSAGE I also become the whole command that are be excuted E:/workspace blabal gitlog ...  and in the second line i become the git message can we disable the whole command i only need the git message

Comment: Your git message would be in `${GIT_MESSAGE}`. This echo part is only for illustration of the value, you can do with the value whatever you want, not necessarily echo it.